# prepareForSegue called before performSegue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to perform a segue that passes a number of variables to the next view including one variable, currentID, which is retrieved from a parse database. performSegue should not be called until after currentID has been set to the currentID downloaded from the database. However, when I run the code, currentID ends up being an empty string when it is passed to the next view.

Here is my code called by the Button:

```
@IBAction func submitButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let point = PFGeoPoint(latitude:0.0, longitude:0.0)
    let testObject = PFObject(className: "Person")

    testObject["inputAmount"] = inputAmount
    testObject["outputAmount"] = outputAmount
    testObject["inputCurrency"] = inputCurrency
    testObject["outputCurrency"] = outputCurrency
    testObject["location"] = point

    testObject.saveInBackground { (success, error) -> Void in

        // added test for success 11th July 2016

        if success {
            print("Object has been saved.")

            self.currentID = String(describing: testObject.objectId!)
            if(self.currentID != ""){
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainToListSegue", sender: self)
            }

        } else {
            if error != nil {
                print (error)
            } else {
                print ("Error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let listViewController = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! ListViewController
    listViewController.inputCurrency = inputCurrency
    listViewController.outputCurrency = outputCurrency
    listViewController.inputAmount = inputAmount
    listViewController.outputAmount = outputAmount
    listViewController.currentID = currentID
    listViewController.cellContent = cellContent
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have you connected your segue to your button ?

Comment: How do I get currentID to not be an empty string when it is passed to the next view?

Comment: Yes my segue is connected to the button

Comment: The segue works fine and goes to the next view. But currentID is an empty string when I try to print it

Comment: that's your problem... when you need to prepare your segue, you MUST connect your segue between your viewcontrollers... yellow round icon to another in your storyboard... delete your actual segue and do it, name it again and it will work

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works now

Comment: an up in the answer is appreciated if it helped you ;-)

Comment: Seems someone posted your answer after you had given it, @GIJOW. Tag me if you post your own and I'll throw the up vote on it.

Comment: Thank you @JakeT. there is my answer. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve your needs, you MUST connect your segue between viewcontrollers, and not from UIButton to viewcontroller.

Every time you need to prepare your segue before calling it, this is the procedure:

[image]

Then, name it and use delegate method

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For navigating from one controller to another, connect your segue from view controller instead of from the button and it will work.